# Powershell resolving file with environmental path

Tags: powershell, path, environment-variables

I have the following function that takes a file name and resolves it either locally, or with the environmental path. I'm looking for the same functionality as you get on the command line:

```
function Resolve-AnyPath ($file)
{
    if ($result = Resolve-Path $file -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    {
        return $result;
    }

    return ($env:PATH -split ';') |
        foreach {
            $testPath = Join-Path $_ $file
            Resolve-Path $testPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        } |
        select -first 1
}
```

My questions:

1. Is there a built-in function that does this?
2. Or a community script that's better?
3. Did I miss anything with my function above?

Comment: do you want this for exe's or any file?

Comment: I would like it for all files, although if there's an easy way to do it for executables (and bat/ps1 files), please post that too. Note, however, that PS prompt allows you to open any file type from PATH. The only thing is that it doesn't do auto-completion for non-executables.

Comment: Get-Command will do it for exe's in the path.

Comment: @acv55 Regarding this comment "that PS prompt allows you to open any file type from PATH" - I don't think that is true. It will only find those files who's extension is in $env:PATHEXT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot think of any built-in function that does this. I'd use `Test-Path` to get rid of those `SilentlyContinue`:

```
function Resolve-Anypath
{
    param ($file)

    (".;" + $env:PATH).Split(";") | ForEach-Object {
        $testPath = Join-Path $_  $file
        if (Test-Path $testPath) {
            Write-Output ($testPath)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For exes (and other extensions in $env:PATHEXT), you can use `Get-Command`.  It will search the path e.g.:

```
C:\PS> Get-Command ProcExp.exe | Foreach {$_.Path}
C:\Bin\procexp.exe
```